# Class _NSZombie_xxxxxxx is implemented in both ?? and?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

We just started seeing these messages appearing in the debug area (console) of Xcode when we navigate to the view controller where the GMSMapView gets created.  Everything seems to be working fine, we just don't like messages like this in the logs.  We don't see them every run, just enough to take notice.  Is this something to worry about?

```
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_PBString is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_PBString is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_PBString is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_PBString is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_PBString is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_GMMResourceResponseProto_Response is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_GMMResourceResponseProto is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_GMMResourceResponseProto is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[15874]: Class _NSZombie_GMSx_GMMResourceResponseProto is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Go to Product (Toolbar) -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme. Under the run tab, choose diagnostics. Is "Enable Zombie Objects" turned on?

Comment: @Hayden Hooligan I already have that turned on, but thanks!

Comment: Those logs are showing up because it's turned ON :P If you turn zombies off they should disappear. Zombies should only be turned on when you're trying to debug a memory leak or crash

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. Now that you mention it, it makes perfect sense.  Thanks! Please create an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Why don't similar logs appear using other third-party libraries? I think there should be duplicate symbols causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSZombies is turned on. Go to product -> scheme -> edit scheme (CMD+SHIFT+.) and under run -> diagnostics uncheck "Enable Zombies".

Comment: THANK YOU. This fixed the "Xcode: Could not attach to pid" error for me